# Annotate Flask-Resource in another file

Tags: python, flask, swagger, flask-restplus

I have two files. The main file creates and starts the API. The task.py file contains one task (in this example only the get method). I can not figure out a way to add the namespace parameter to the class (constructor does not work as it is not in the instance but in the class itself). I have also tried to add it to a third file and import it in both classes from there. If I do so I get an Import Error. Sorry if the solution is trivial but I am rather new to Python.

main.py

```py
from task import MyTask

app = Flask(__name__)

api = Api(app, version='1.0', title="Title",
              description='Description')

namespace = api.namespace('task', description='Description2')
namespace.add_ressource(MyTask, "/task")
```

task.py

```py
@namespace.param('task_id', 'The task identifier.')
class MyTask(Resource):
    def get(self, task_id):
        return task
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this:

main.py

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api
from task import namespace as taskns

app = Flask(__name__)

api = Api(app, version='1.0', title="Title",
            description='Description')

api.add_namespace(taskns)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

task.py

```py
from flask_restplus import Namespace, Resource

namespace = Namespace('task', description='Description2')

@namespace.route("/<int:task_id>")
@namespace.param('task_id', 'The task identifier.')
class MyTask(Resource):
    '''Fetch a single task item'''
    @namespace.doc('get_task')
    def get(self, task_id):
        return f"Fetching {task_id}..."
```

Reference: https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scaling.html